# Swagger-UI generics mapping

Tags: java, generics, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

is there anyway to correct Map method responses which use generics as response subfields with the appropriate implementation? Example:

Let's say I have a generic response class:

```
public class Response {
    private String createdOn;
    //other fields
    private Map<String, Object> values;
    private Model object;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Generic model class:

```
public class Model{
}
```

Model Class A:

```
public class ModelA extends Model{
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    //getters and setters
}
```

And Model Class B:

```
public class ModelB extends Model{
    private int number;
    private boolean isTrue;
    //getters and setters
}
```

And method doSomeStuff() which let's say returns a ResponseEntity< Response> where in this particular response "values" is a map< String, SomeRandomObject> and object is a ModelA object.

And suppose I have another method doSomeOtherStuff() which returns a ResponseEntity< Response> object where in that case "values" is a map< String, AnotherRandomObject> and object is a ModelB object.

Is there any way to map the response subfields of the first method to the appropriate ones? Using swagger-UI all I get is the following for both methods:

```
{
  "createdOn": "string",
  // other fields
  "model": {},
  "values": {}
}
```

Whereas I would like something like the following:
doSomeStuff():

```
{
  "createdOn": "string",
  // other fields
  "model": {
    "name": "string",
    "lastname": "string",
  }
  "model": {
    //All the subfields of SomeRandomObject
  },
}
```

doSomeOtherStuff():

```
{
  "createdOn": "string",
  // other fields
  "model": {
    "number": "int",
    "isTrue": "boolean",
  }
  "model": {
    //All the subfields of AnotherRandomObject
  },
}
```

Since it obviously cannot determine what type of objects are returned at the implementation level.

P.S. The above classes are as an example. I would really appreciate help to make the documentation work and not for ways to refactor it since the above logic is applied to more than 100 rest methods.

Edit: I am using springfox-swagger2 with springfox-swagger-ui.

Comment: Which framework do you use - Springfox?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention it. I am updating the question.